# Finding the right count syntax in mySQL select statement

Tags: php, mysql, count, left-join

Goal: 
To have a table of SIC codes with their descriptions (joined via another table) and count the number of instances of each DISTINCT SIC code used.  Ideal outcome below...followed by current mySQL select statement:

```
SIC Code | Description | Count of SIC Code
0001     | Desc A      | 10               
0002     | Desc B      | 50               
000N     | Desc N      | 80
```

Current SQL Statement, but causing error notice:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT company_list.SIC_Codes, sic_codes.SIC_desc, COUNT(*) as sicCount, FROM company_list LEFT JOIN sic_codes ON company_list.SIC_Codes = sic_codes.SIC_code;";
```

Any ideas or perspective on which count syntax to use to obtain the example above?

Thank you.

Comment: I think even without any error, you will still not achieve your desired result since if you put `COUNT` in the select query, it will always return only 1 result and not all.

Comment: @BCH any clue on table structure..? anyway, previous comment is right you had to group the `Description` and `SIC Code` first to make `COUNT()` works..

Comment: for you error problem. I think you should remove the `;` next to `sic_codes.SIC_code`.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a subquery for `COUNT` something like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT company_list.SIC_Codes, sic_codes.SIC_desc, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM company_list LEFT JOIN sic_codes ON company_list.SIC_Codes = sic_codes.SIC_code) as sicCount, FROM company_list LEFT JOIN sic_codes ON company_list.SIC_Codes = sic_codes.SIC_code";
```

Instead of putting the `COUNT` as field, try making a subquery for it. 
Change `COUNT(*)` to `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM company_list LEFT JOIN sic_codes ON company_list.SIC_Codes = sic_codes.SIC_code)`

Comment: Mark - Thank you for the ideas...I worked with it a while and then went back and believe I have found a solution...$sql = "SELECT company_list.SIC_codes, sic_codes.SIC_desc, COUNT(1) as sicCount FROM company_list LEFT JOIN sic_codes ON company_list.SIC_codes = sic_codes.SIC_code GROUP BY company_list.SIC_codes ORDER BY sicCount DESC";  this appears to give me every "SIC code" in table 1 and its description in table 2 and a count of them.   any concerns with this approach?  Thank  you.